# Where are "Discussions" from Google Patents?

Tags: google-patents, meta-question, forums

When I look for patents online using Google Patents, I get the list of ranked candidate patent with several links (eg "Overview", "Correlations", "Talk with others" (note that I am translating from Italian, and the English version might differ)).

When I click on "Talk to others", they try to redirect to an external page but fail.
However, the page is somehow liked to this forum.
For example, for [this](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6026414?oq=US5689701A) link, I get redirected to https://www.google.com/url?ptose&q=//%20%20patents.stackexchange.com**/redirect/google-patents?patent%3DUS6026414&usg=AOvVaw2lXlomYmNxUhpVjibk9YnU

Does StackExchange contain pages in which people talk of individual patents? How do I find them? Do they have a particular tag? I am interested because of an unrelated NLP project.

Comment: To summarize, that link should not exist, but it generates traffic so nobody important is complaining.

Comment: Thank you for yourr clarification. Do you know if any such forums (where people discuss individual patents - even a few, specific ones) - exist?

Comment: There are some blogs looking for example at standard essential patents (but mostly at the court proceedings around them), but other than that no, I don't know any. It's hard to find people interested in the same patent, there are, after all, millions.

Comment: Do you have a particular example in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking the "Discuss" link seems to take you to the Ask Patents SE site and search on a tag with the patent number (at least for a US user). It's unfortunate the link is named "Discuss" since Stack Exchange isn't a discussion forum. Rather it is a question and answer site. To my knowledge there is no feature on Ask Patents related to discussion on individual patents. One might try the [Ask Patents Meta](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com) site, but that site is even less populated.

If you have a specific question about a patent or patents then I encourage you to ask a specific question on Ask Patents. If you have technical questions about natural language processing then there are probably other more appropriate SE sites such as the [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nlp) SE site.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know if similar forums (where people discuss individual patents or a class of patents) exist, anywhere else?

Comment: @ImAUser I don’t, but I’ll look around.